# Read coordinates from WMS or WFS service

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, wms

I'm currently developing an application for IOS, Android and Windows Phone with google map based on Open Data. The Open Data is available on WMS or WFS format but I want extract the coordinates from this services to obtain JSON (because I want put informations contains in it on the Google Map with personnal informations).

I tried to get the flux with geoserver and expose it as JSON for the interesting layer but it doesn't work.

How I can do that ? Is it possible to get it directly on Android, Windows Phone and Iphone and add it to the google map ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WMS is known as Web Map Service and does not usually provide data (although you can use getFeatureInfo, but not all geoserver implementations support json output), instead you can use WFS requests (get or post) to obtain data you need.
WFS does support json (using parameter OUTPUT=application/json ) and allows filters (both spatial and based on attributes) and limit features. You should check the official documentation for detailed query specification; I suggest to use version 1.1.0